# Effect of BookSleev.Redis asynchronous set without await

Tags: c#, async-await, booksleeve

Putting await for async method call is mandatory in .net ?? For example,
I have a redis set command that I don't want to wait for.

```
 .....statements....
await redis.Hashes.Set(db, mainKey, value);
.....statements after set command......
```

I don't want to pause the execution of my method in set command. So I removed 'await'.

```
.....statements....
redis.Hashes.Set(db, mainKey, value);
....statements after set command......
```

Is this a good practice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to not await a Task, but I not sure it's good practice. If there are exceptions thrown in the called Task you won't know about them.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh965065.aspx

Also, Booksleeve has been deprecated for quite a while now, and is replaced by [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis). You should probably look to use that instead, if possible.

StackExchange.Redis has a `CommandFlags.FireAndForget` parameter that you can specify which will immediately return the default value and not wait around for the command to complete.

```
connection.GetDatabase().HashSet(key, field, value, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget)
```

[Documentation for FireAndForget](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md#fire-and-forget)

Comment: Thanks, which is better? I can see a big difference in execution time between ConnectionProvider.GetConnection<RedisConnection>(); of Booksleev and connectionProvider.GetMultiplexer().GetDatabase(); of stackexchange. Booksleeve is far away better in connection time - i feel so. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I would definitely recommend StackExchange.Redis over Booksleeve. Booksleeve is no longer maintained, and SE.Redis has better support for modern redis feature including failover, clusters, etc... Here's Mark Gravell's blog entry explaining why SE.Redis was written as a replacement - http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/03/so-i-went-and-wrote-another-redis-client.html

Comment: Regarding the connection time, I don't know what Booksleeve does internally, but SE.Redis maintains and automatically tries to reconnect to configured redis instances. Since connections are persistent, the connection time shouldn't be a major factor in your decision about which library to use.